# How to check if a WCF service is available?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-proxy

Can I use `Proxy.Open()` as an indication to whether the connection should work or not?
I would like to check if a connection is available first, and then, if its not, i won't make any calls to the service during the run of the application.

Note: I only need to check connectivity, not necessarily and entire client-service round-trip.

I Ended up creating a Ping() methods in the service as suggested.

FYI, using simply Open() just didn't work - Open() doesn't raise any exceptions even if the service is offline!

Comment: I always add a do-nothing method `Ping` to my services, and call that method before doing any real communication. I would be curious to find out if there are built-in alternatives, though.

Comment: That can tell you if you can open the connection **right now** - but 5 milliseconds later, your actual call can still fail. There's just really no point in trying to *check* this - you won't gain any useful information from that. You just **must** be prepared for any WCF call to fail - and handle it appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that there are so many variables which influence success of a WCF Service call, I tend to add a dummy void KnockKnock()) method to the services to have a real proof if the connection works.

This method can also serve a double purpose: You can call it async to notify the server that he has to be prepared for incoming requests. (Just the initial start-up of the service may take some time.) By invoking the KnockKnock() method the server can start loading the service and give your clients a better initial response performance.

Comment: Thanks, Please see my added note, do you think Open() will do for a simple connectivity check?

Comment: It will open a network connection to your server - and upon success set the State property to "Opened". This way you can check the current network connection but it does not guarantee that the service will run. (Because Open() won't init the service.) -> I would simply go for a dummy method.